# Insert a new record with autogenerated id

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to insert a new record into a simple database table with MyBatis but I get a strange exception. Mybe it is related to that I am not using POJO.

MyBatis version: 3.4.5

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    content BYTEA
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

MyBatis mapper:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO image (id, content) VALUES (#{id}, #{content})")
@SelectKey(statement = "SELECT NEXTVAL('image_seq')", keyProperty = "id", before = true, resultType = long.class)
long insertImage(byte[] content);
```

The way I am trying to use it:

```
byte[] fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
long id = imageDao.insertImage(fileContent);
```

The exception what I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [B
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.ByteArrayTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ByteArrayTypeHandler.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:86)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:49)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

I do not want to create POJO class with getter/setter method for this one "content" param but I think this issue is related to missing POJO.

What is the solution?

**EDIT**

I am trying to debug mybatis code and I have found "`[B`" in the `parameterTypes`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@SelectKey` is useful when you want to reuse generated value farther in the code, but it seems yo will not.

Then why not keep everything in the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO image (id, content) VALUES ((SELECT NEXTVAL('image_seq')), #{content})
```

For exception regarding parameters, parameters must be named with `@Param` annotation

```
int insertImage(@Param("content") byte[] content);
```

or

```
int insertImage(@Param("id) Long id, @Param("content") byte[] content)
```

Note that INSERT as well as UPDATE and DELETE statements returns type int being the number of inserted/updated/deleted rows, [...]

**EDIT:** unless you consider that under the hood, the java 8 [`PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeLargeUpdate--) returning long is executed.

[...] and not the generated key as it is suggested. Then it seems you eventually want to get the key value, that means back to square one with `@SelectKey` and need for a POJO and a target property for the generated value. It even works with bulk insert with generated keys.

I have discovered lately that  actual parameters name can be used (then your code will work as is) if following instructions in [settings section of the documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html):

> `useActualParamName` Allow referencing statement parameters by their
>   actual names declared in the method signature. To use this feature,
>   your **project must be compiled in Java 8 with -parameters option**.
>   (Since: 3.4.1)    valid values: `true` | `false`  default: `true`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Finnally I have created a POJO with id, comment, filename and length properties. It makes sense to store these metadata with the file content. And of coure the POJO solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [B

This is saying that you are trying to convert `long` to `byte[]`

Looking at source of `org.apache.ibatis.type.ByteArrayTypeHandler`:

```
public void  setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, byte[] parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    ps.setBytes(i, parameter);
}
```

I think you need to remove `{id}` from insert annotation (as this value is autogenerated).

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO image (content) VALUES (#{content})")
```

Otherwise parameters are shifted by one.

Comment: As per your suggestion I removed id from sql but it did not help. I got this strange exception: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'content' not found. Available parameters are [array, id]

Comment: I removed @SelectKey and added a long input parameter to the method signature like this: long insertImage(long id, byte[] content). But now this is the exception I got: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found. Available parameters are [arg1, arg0, param1, param2]  I am confised a little bit where this 4 params in the log come from.